# Want a restriction of category post created from admin wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a two category

category 1 and category 2

If i want to restrict to two post from the category 1 and restrict to three posts from the category 2 when i publish the post from the admin

Is that possible to do? Any help or resources will be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this..https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/exclude-the-category-from-the-wordpress-loop

Comment: sorry but i need to restrict it from admin side means category 1 post publish only 2 time after that validation fire.